Problem with pymodbus Modbus RTU (Serial) between PLC with NUL values?
I am trying to get data from my PLC to my PC(Python).
Currently I'm using Modbus RTU Serial communication with pymodbus.
But there are some problems with the sent/received data, and I don't know if it's problem in which side. Please help
Status :

Sending from Python [97, 98, 99, 49, 50, 51] to PLC data D100


code below, prints error msg like :
Fail to write data Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 4 bytes (0 received)


However, in PLC (XG5000) I made a Modbus Server(Slave) and it receives the data as :
-> NUL DLE NUL d NUL ACK FF NUL a NUL b NUL c NUL 1 NUL 2 NUL 3  G

and sends response
-> NUL DLE NUL d NUL ACK NUL ENQ
and when I check D100~D108, the data sent is saved well in ascii code.
Modbus slave

when trying to receive data from PLC D100~D104,
PLC receive the request as :
-> NUL ETX NUL d NUL EOT EOT BEL
and send response as :
-> NUL ETX BS NUL a NUL b NUL c NUL 1 )
so I can see the data abc1 is trying? to be sent? but in python it again gets this error :
Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 4 bytes (0 received)

Please let me understand any problems here.
Any comments are welcome! Thanks

The abc123 is what you are sending (and it's not Modbus RTU - I don't know these PLC's so that may be your intention). Can you please clarify what you are sending (if it should be Modbus RTU then, perhaps, start with a known good tool like MBPoll/ModPoll).
